# Running app from console gets CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'

Tags: xcode, xctool

I am trying to run an iOS app from the console executing the following command:

```
xctool/xctool.sh -workspace Supermaxi.xcworkspace -scheme Supermaxi build
```

and I am getting this response

[Info] Loading settings for scheme 'Supermaxi' ... (11036 ms)

```
=== BUILD ===

  xcodebuild build Supermaxi
    Pods / Pods-FunctionalTests-KIF (Debug)
      ✓ Check dependencies (379 ms)
      0 errored, 0 warning (442 ms)

    Pods / Pods-uservoice-iphone-sdk-UserVoice (Debug)
      0 errored, 0 warning (159 ms)

    ✓ Check dependencies (144 ms)
    Pods / Pods-uservoice-iphone-sdk (Debug)
      ✓ Check dependencies (468 ms)
      0 errored, 0 warning (850 ms)

    Pods / Pods-FunctionalTests (Debug)
      0 errored, 0 warning (186 ms)

    ✓ Check dependencies (184 ms)
    Pods / Pods (Debug)
      ✓ Check dependencies (18 ms)
      0 errored, 0 warning (20 ms)

    Supermaxi / Supermaxi (Debug)
      ✗ Check dependencies (0 ms)
```

and the following error:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “NV6RLEM7VP” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
      2 errored, 0 warning (0 ms)



Failures:

  0) Check dependencies
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “NV6RLEM7VP” were found.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

** BUILD FAILED ** (3095 ms)
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading several posts at stackoverflow and several post at Github, I found [this one](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3047) where I found a solution at the end. Therefore, my solution was:

```
xctool/xctool.sh -workspace Supermaxi.xcworkspace -scheme Supermaxi build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

It worked for me.

Comment: For me, it was sufficient to include the following `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,OS=9.2'` and the build worked